# Error when saving individual docs from a mail merge

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I Have been using a VBA code to individually save all letters separately from a mail merge into a designated folder. It has always worked previously howver with the document I am trying to do it for now it is onyl saving the first document and then coming up with an error stating:

run-time error '5825' object has been deleted

When I go to debug it highlights the line near the bottom reading 'DocResult.Close False'

How can I fix this?

Tried changing this to True or deleting line entirely but does not fix problem. Each document is quite large so takes approx 30 seconds to save

```
Dim WithEvents wdapp As Application
Dim bCustomProcessing As Boolean

Private Sub Document_Open()

Set wdapp = Application
bCustomProcessing = False
ThisDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = 1
ThisDocument.MailMerge.ShowWizard 1
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
   If .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters Then
       .ShowSendToCustom = "Custom Letter Processing"
   End If
End With

End Sub
Private Sub wdapp_MailMergeWizardSendToCustom(ByVal Doc As Document)

bCustomProcessing = True
Doc.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
With Doc.MailMerge
    For rec = 1 To .DataSource.RecordCount
        .DataSource.ActiveRecord = rec
        .DataSource.FirstRecord = rec
        .DataSource.LastRecord = rec
        .Execute
    Next
End With

MsgBox "Merge Finished"
End Sub


Private Sub wdapp_MailMergeAfterMerge(ByVal Doc As Document, ByVal DocResult As Document)
If bCustomProcessing = True Then
    With Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields
        sFirmFileName = .Item(44).Value ' First Column of the data - CHANGE
    End With
    DocResult.SaveAs "xxx\" & sFirmFileName & ".doc", wdFormatDocument
     ' Path and File Name to save. can use other formats like wdFormatPDF too
    DocResult.Close False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: did you try `DocResult.Close`

Comment: I did but unfortunately I got the same error

Comment: I think you must do this : `Set DocResult = nothing` and delete `DocResult.Close False` . I think it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set your object as nothing like this :

`Set DocResult = nothing`